# Photoshop - Text to stone engraving effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, photoshop-effects, depth

I have a oil painting style monastery wall to start with. I would like to add a customizable text onto it, line by line, starting with something like "the following is an epic tale". I'm sure the Latin is totally wrong, but can use it for proof of concept for now:

[image]

My desired effect would be:

- Visible depth: it looks like an engraving, holes that go into the wall
- If possible, some artifacts that would randomly appear to help sell the effect, like small cracks, suggesting maybe when the engraver split the wall too hard. (and avoiding uniformity)

### Question

What would an example workflow look like from the picture above to my desired effects?

#### Bonus points

Totally optional, but feel free to recommend a font that was likely used to engrave in ancient times. It would appear that this manuscript style font might not be the most realistic.

### Edit

I was pleasantly surprised by how far [this](https://www.tipsquirrel.com/creating-a-chiseled-text-effect-in-photoshop-and-photoshop-elements/) tutorial got me. But half of my desired effect was not addressed. And this seems to be the case more generally for `hard-chisel` tutorials: they are for clean, sharp-looking applications. To be clear, I'm still looking for clean and sharp, but also visible signs of weathering/aging, ergo the "artifacts" and/or cracks that randomly shoot off of some of the letters.

Comment: What have you tired? Where is that failing?

Comment: @Scott It's more that I'm stuck, unable to work towards my goal. It barely merits a mention, but all I was able to think of was `Blending options`->`Drop shadow` but that was too smooth/soft/amorphous and, just in general did not have the configurables for a perspective consistent, sharp engraving effect.

Comment: A Google search for "Photoshop Text to stone engraving effect" will uncover hundreds of tutorials. There's not a great deal of value in asking users to repeat things here. I'd suggest you do this first, then ask if you run into any problems with a particular tutorial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a brief overview of one way you could do it.

1. Type some text. For the font, many old/ancient inscriptions used square capitals only with no lower case. You could use something like Trajan, it has full size capitals, and lower case as small capitals.
2. To roughen it up a bit start with an already more textured stone background.
3. Apply a Bevel and Emboss layer style to the text layer.
4. Add a Pattern Overlay layer style, choose a rough pattern texture
5. Add a Drop Shadow layer style

Here are the settings I used for the 3 layers styles, but you may have to tweak them depending on the size of your text or how you want it to look.

[image]Click to enlarge

6. Set the layer blending mode of the text layer to Lighter Color, or experiment with other blend modes, each will give a slightly different effect.

Here's the example at 100% zoom

[image]

7. To add cracks, find a cracked stone/concrete texture, put it on a layer of its own above the other layers, and set its blending mode to Darken

[image]